# Can't upload images on StackExchange

Tags: bug, images, imgur, uploader

I can't seem to be able to upload a picture to my stackexchange question [Add notification for events on my Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/add-notification-for-events-on-my-raspberry-pi).

The upload dialog just keeps on running without any results.

> Uploading [image: uploading]

I tried to upload a picture of the uploading process here, but that did not work either.

This has been like this for me for a few days now.

**Update**:

I am using Safari version 8.0.8 (10600.8.9)

I did click the Image icon or hit `CTRL + G`  and then drag an image from my Desktop to the imgur overlay.

The image is ~160kB in size.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using? Also, how are you trying to upload? Drag and drop? Dialog? From the web? Do you know if Imgur is being blocked by your computer or network?

Comment: Check the developer console in your browser to see if you get any client side errors.

Comment: What size, in bytes, is the image?

Comment: Could you upload the same image directly on [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) It should work, if not then there is some issue with your image. Once uploaded, leave a comment here with link to img url here so that we can look into.

Comment: @Oded there is a similar bug [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266102/uploading-images-issue-across-sites#comment863503_266102) that includes the error in the dev console. I couldn't figure out a root cause, so it is up to you now...

Comment: We can't reproduce here (also using Safari 8.0.8) - is this still an issue? Can you confirm what errors you see in the dev console?

Comment: Are you blocking any content on the sites (ads, 3rd party domains)?

Comment: @Oded I do "Allow Cookies from pages I visit". I don't get any errors in the console and I could upload an image with imgur directly [sample image](http://i.imgur.com/hB3HGrH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem, was the cookies setting "Allow from websites I visit". So as soon as I did visit imgur.com and uploaded an image there, I could then upload the image on stackexchange.

However, I did not have this problem, when the "old" image uploader was in place. Personally, I am reluctant to allow cookies for sites I don't visit.